# Does GCP MFA Allow For Trusted Devices?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Okay so recently I started working with Firebase and I noticed that on GCP's Identity Platform there is the option to enable MFA for your users. Given the fact that I needed this in my app I thought this would be a great fit. However after reading the very limited documentation (found here: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa)and implementing this solution I do not see any real way to add an option to trust a users device, hence not bothering the user to have to verify with the second step every time they log in.

So my question is does this feature exist within GCP's MFA or does this have to be worked out some other way? If this feature exists does anyone know how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trusted device is currently not supported by GCP Identity Platform.

I recently had the same question when implementing MFA for a web app. My research included contacting GCP with this question and got the answer that there is currently no feature for trusted client/device and therefor not possible to avoid the second factor authentication (even with a custom implementation). Once you have enabled MFA you cannot temporarily disable it.